# c++ allocate array syntax question

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator

You can write like this:

```
int test[] = {1,2,3,4};
```

but what if you want to use a pointer and allocate it with new?

```
int *test2;
test2 = new int[]{1,2,3,4};
```

This does not work, what is the syntax or is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inline array initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583628/inline-array-initialization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the short-comings of current standard C++. Initialization is not *uniform*. Your best hope [is uniform initialization in C++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Uniform_initialization), but for the mean while you can assign the values after creating the array, e.g.

```
int *test2;
test2 = new int[4]; // Note that you still have to specify the size in C++0x
test2[0] = 1;
test2[1] = 2;
test2[2] = 3;
test2[3] = 4;
```

Comment: There is also Boost.Assign, if you're willing to play around with that.

Comment: @jalf Yep I used it & loved it, but these days I use g++ 4.6 and C++0x support is quit impressive :)

Answer (score 3):

If you compiler [supports C++0x](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#init-list)

```
int *test2;
test2 = new int[4] {1,2,3,4}; // Initializer list in C++0x
```

would work. However you should always use `std::vector` instead of C style arrays while writing good C++ code.

Comment: If you don't need a dynamic array, you shouldn't use it. If a static array is suitable, adding complexity to the problem doesn't make it "good c++ code". Keep it simple.

Comment: @Simon : I was just suggesting a possible solution to the problem. Nothing much!

Comment: Sauray: no, you weren't 'just suggesting a solution'. That was your first sentence. Your second sentence offered advice that Simon and I don't agree with. But +1 for your first sentence :-)

Answer (score 2):

The first syntax is called aggregate initialization, and you cannot apply it to a dynamically allocated array. When allocating dynamically you must provide the number of elements that you want to initialize inside the square brackets and (optionally) the default value in parenthesis (if you want the array initialised). The default value will be the same (if present) for all elements.

You may want to look into the boost::assign library that may have support for this type of initialization (not sure). Alternatively you can (at the cost of more code) do it yourself for POD types:

```
int * array = new int[4];
{
   int values[] = { 1,2,3,4 };
   memcpy( array, values, sizeof(values) );
}
```

Or for non-pod types:

```
type * array = new type[4];
{
   type values[] = { 1,2,3,4 }; // assuming type(int) constructor
   std::copy( values, values+4, array ); // better to use some magic to calculate size
}
```

At any rate both of those solutions require allocating locally and the *copying* (bit-size/c++) into the dynamically allocated memory.